# Is there a key combination to cycle through clipboard history when pasting in windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, paste

In Visual Studio, I can cycle through my clipboard history by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+V` rather than `CTRL+V`. I believe it's called a clipboard ring. But that feature doesn't seem to exist outside of Visual Studio, at least not with the same key combination. Is there a key stroke combination built in to windows to do the same, i.e. be able to cycle through your clipboard history while pasting?

Comment: dunno about win7, did you assume that it does? Winxp has no clipboard history! For win xp at least, Look at c:\windows\system32\clipbrd.exe   it's pretty crappy. You may need an alternative.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Honestly, I just assumed that the feature would work the same, independent of windows version - seems that may not be the case. And I wasn't aware that XP had no clipboard history.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows (7 and previous versions) does not have such a built-in clipboard management feature; but you might want to read the following article:

http://lifehacker.com/5298615/five-best-clipboard-managers

I recommend [ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) and [clipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/).

Comment: The question linked to has been 'removed from Super User for reasons of moderation'.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: so how do you cycle anyways?

Answer (score 5):

As of Windows 10 version 1809, Windows now has built-in clipboard history.
You can push <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to show it.

Note that this is still has many fewer features than Ditto, so that would still be a good option to consider.