# Is there any way to get previous copied content?

Tags: data-recovery

I am using **Windows 7**. There was a txt File in flash drive. I opened it using **Notepad** and copied small text(Around 30 words). Then I removed the flash drive and I have no access (Physically) to the flash drive now.

Then I went to paste that text in to another text file on my hard disk. But, I accidentally copied another thing before paste. So my preview copied text was gone. Is there way to get the previous copied content?

Comment: You will need to provide more context before anyone can help you, such as your OS and the program you used to open the text files.

Comment: It's a little unclear. Did you write another text file in the location of the old one ? How large was it ? Is the file saved or still open ?

Comment: If you don't have already a clipboard manager tool installed and active, then most likely you can't recover that information.

Comment: @NathanShiraini I updated the question with more information. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/250253/is-there-a-key-combination-to-cycle-through-clipboard-history-when-pasting-in-wi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 keeps only the last entry of the clipboard and drops (=forget) the previous one.

There are clipboard manager tools ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager), [another](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-free-clipboard-history-managers-track-copy-paste/)) which store clipboard content and let user access multiple entries, but they can work since you install them.
So the answer is your question is that you can't recover the content of the clipboard if you don't have already such a tool installed.